# Как в objective-c объявить переменную глобальной?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

имеются 2 tableview со списками, и пустой экран. я не знаю как мне сделать так чтобы на пустом экране выходил тест с учетом выбраного мною пункта!!! для этого мне нужно узнать indexPath.row я это уже сделал(ибо у меня не получилась бы переход с 1 таблицы на 2, и показывались нужные пункты) но когда я пишу в условии ПУСТОГО ЭКРАНА про 1 таблицу(номмер нажатой строки) он пишет не задеклорирвана перемнная! 
поэтому я решил, что в этом случаи мне нужно класс с первой ТаБЛицой СДЕЛАТЬ ГЛОБАЛЬНЫМ! для того чтобы с пустого экрана я мог импортировать эту переменную(со значение номера нажатия первой таблицы)

вот ссылка на мой код!!!

http://webfile.ru/0b65e007063c022aef9a5ff9906734c9

кому несложно ПОСМАТРИТЕ ПОЖАЛЙСТА!!!! И ОБЬЯСНИТЕ КАК ЭТО СДЕЛАТЬ))) НАДЕЮСЬ НА ВАШЕ ПОНИМАНИЕ

первая таблица: 
 1. овощи 2. фрукты. 3 ягоды.

вторая таблица исходит от того, на какой пункт нажали в первой таблице:
 если фрукты -- то 1. яблоко 2. бананы 3. мандарины и так далее
 или если овощи то --- 1. картошка 2. лук 3. огурцы

пустой экран:

на этом экране ничего нет! но я хочу сделать сдесь текст соответсвующей выбору двух предущих пунктов!
например если мы выбрали картошка: то должно выходить фото его и небольшой текст

Comment: @SPARTAK, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. @SPARTAK, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Comment: мне необходиммо импортировать из одного класса в другой значение переменой. я не знаю как это оформить?

Comment: http://webfile.ru/0b65e007063c022aef9a5ff9906734c9  -- вот ссылка на мой код !! был бы очень вам всем признателен, если бы вы взгялунли на него!!!

Comment: @SPARTAK запускается и пустой экран.

Comment: @SPARTAK, лазить по Вашему дереву файлов что-то нет желания.

Может относящиеся к делу фрагменты файлов приведете здесь (в **update** вопроса)?

--

Кстати, а тривиальный `extern` уже не работает?

Comment: я даже незнаю как вам обьяснить свою проблему. у меня на данный момент работает все!!! но мне нужно сделать экран с информацией если я буду делать условие, из предыдущего tableview этого не достаточно! вот что получается наприер:

я выбрал фрукты: затем яблоко : затем выходит какой то текст 

но если я выбираю например овощи: затем картошку: выходит тот же текст что и яблоко (если они на одной и той же строчке)

Comment: а мне нужно узнать на какую строчку я нажал при выборе : фрукты или овощи!!!

Comment: должно быть в условии 2 переменные!!!!
одна с этого класса а другая с 1-ого tableview
но если я указываю в (экран информации) переменную tableview выходит ошибка не задиклорирована переменная

Comment: если бы вы посматрели мой код !!! то вам бы сразу стало ясно о чем я говорю))))))))

Comment: на счет кода что выходит пустой лист, этого не может быть !!! только что скачал с этой ссылки открыл и запустил !! все как нужно все работает))) даже  не знаю в чем причина

Answer (score 2):

Так как вы хотите (через глобальную переменную) не делается, делается все гораздо проще (в общем случае мы всегда передаем объект из одного UIViewController в другой), есть метод `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // вот тут у вас есть indexPath - то есть "номер строки" в табличке
     /* берем объект, например если они у вас объекты лежат в массиве objects, то будет так */ id myFruitObject = self.objects[indexPath.row]; /* если в другом месте, следовательно достаем объект оттуда */
     // дальше создаем следующий детальный экран
     MyDetailsVC *vc = [MyDetailsVC new];
     // передаем в него наш объект, скажем это было яблоко, чтобы такая конструкция сработала вам нужно будет в MyDetailsVC объявить @property (nonatomic, strong) id object;
     vc.object = myFruitObject;
     // показываем экран с описанием
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

если же вы используете storyboard тут дела обстоят немного иначе, напишите в камент я объясню как быть с ней

Для **сториборд** реализуем в своем UIViewController метод

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStorybordSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     // Обычно для segue (переходов) задаются имена, чтобы идентифицировать переход, но если он у вас, скажем, один, можно и без имени
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"details"]) {
        // дальше смысл абсолютно тот же
        // берем из сеги только что созданный UIViewController
        MyDetailsVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        // Получаем индекс того объекта, что мы тока что выбрали
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        // ну и дальше все тоже самое
        if (indexPath) {
            // передаем туда объект
            vc.object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        }
        // единсвенное, чтобы это все работало надо выбрать single selection у UITableViewController и очищать selection при входе на экран, поскольку вам необходимо, что селекшн всегда был один и актуальный
    }
}
```

Comment: да я storyboard работаю

Answer (score 1):

[@SPARTAK](/users/18695/spartak) Вот несколько полезных ссылок. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started - главный ресурс разработчика. Тут и примеры кода и объяснения. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH2-SW1 - тут вводной курс для новичка. Как раз в нем объясняется как можно передавать значения от одного экрана к другому.

Если нет сил и желания все это читать, то посмотрите как создать [singleton](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/). Например можно создать список, к которому можно будет обращаться из любой точки программы.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо использовать глобальные переменные, достаточно добавить `@property`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    myViewController.myProperty = @"какие угодно данные";
    myViewController.myAnotherProperty = indexPath.row; // номер строки
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewControlleranimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: кажется вы меня не поняли

Comment: пример моего приложения:

таблица1: 1. офощи 2. фрукты  3. ягоды
по нажатию на один из этих пунктов происходит переход

например нажали фрукты:
таблица2: 1. яблоки 2. груши 3. мандарины и т.д 
например нажали яблоко

экран с информацией: все про яюлоко! витамины, виды сорта и так далее

Comment: так вот моя проблема в том что: я уже понял как сделать переход, чтоб если я нажимал на фрукты -  выходили яюлоки груши, или если я нажимал на овощи - картошка лук и т.д

у меня не получается ЭКРАН С ИНФОРМАЦИЕЙ!!!
там должно быть описание!

Comment: я делаю условие на ЭКРАНЕ С ИНФОРМАЦИЕЙ

if(_indexObzor = 0){
  _detail.text == "виды сорта: фовфрвло"; 
}
else if(_indexObzor = 0){
  _detail.text == "виды сорта: aawd"; 
}
else if(_indexObzor = 0){
  _detail.text == "виды сорта: awdaw"; 
}

только нужно еще узнать предыдущую строчку нажатия!!! мне нужно добавить в условие номер нажатия строки между таблица1 и таблица 2

Comment: @SPARTAK , приведите где-нибудь код полностью, совершенно непонятно что у вас собственно не получается.

Comment: Как я понял, "пустой экран" это вторая форма, а выбор из таблиц происходит на первой, главной форме, и когда он пытается обратиться к переменным первой формы из второй происходит ошибка декларации. Текст с описанием выбранных наименований отображается на "пустом экране"...